# defining mongodb searching query

Tags: java, mongodb

Hi I'm trying to define a searching query for mongod db entries.

Entries looks like the following one:

```
{
    "_id" : "13132413435452113545452",
    "type" : "U",
    "dataSourceA" : {
        uSet : [ "u", "v", "w"]
    }
}
```

Let's say I have 100 of these entries with `uSet : [ "u", "v", "w"]`

So now I would like to find out which different uSet values exist in my database. For e.g. could another 100 entries with different ids look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "13132413435452113545452",
    "type" : "U",
    "dataSourceA" : {
        uSet : [ "d", "v", "w"]
    }
}
```

and the goal would be a result containing the values `{"d","v","w","u"}`

I don't know where to start to define a query which delivers me the desired values.

Any help or a hint would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible with the [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/) command (for Java see [distinct(…)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#distinct%28java.lang.String%29)).

```
collection.distinct("dataSourceA.uSet");
```